# Calculate partial trace of an outer product in Python?

Tags: linear-algebra, python, quantum-mechanics

I have a python implementation of calculating the partial trace over select dimensions.

```py
def partial_trace(rho, keep, dims):
    """Calculate the partial trace

    Parameters
    ----------
    ρ : 2D array
        Matrix to trace
    keep : array
        An array of indices of the spaces to keep after
        being traced. For instance, if the space is
        A x B x C x D and we want to trace out B and D,
        keep = [0,2]
    dims : array
        An array of the dimensions of each space.
        For instance, if the space is A x B x C x D,
        dims = [dim_A, dim_B, dim_C, dim_D]

    Returns
    -------
    ρ_a : 2D array
        Traced matrix
    """
    dims = np.asarray(dims)
    N = dims.size
    # Indices to trace
    rest = np.delete(np.arange(N), keep)
    # Reshape into tensor
    rho_a = rho.reshape(np.tile(dims, 2))
    # Trace indices
    for i,d in enumerate(rest[::-1]):
        rho_a = np.trace(rho_a, axis1=d, axis2=N-i+d)
    # Reshape into matrix
    N = np.prod(dims[keep])
    return rho_a.reshape(N,N)
```

I would like to calculate the partial trace of $|u\rangle \langle u|$ but I run into an insufficient memory error when I try to construct the outer product.
Instead, I would like to directly calculate the partial trace from $|u \rangle$.

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Are the vectors $|u\rangle$ in $R^n$?

Comment: The elements are complex

Comment: So, $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Isn't in that case: $\mathrm{Tr}(|u\rangle \langle u| ) = \langle u| u\rangle$?

Comment: It would be the case if I trace over the full Hilbert space. I have the tensor product of many Hilbert spaces and I want to trace over only some of the Hilbert spaces, i.e. partial trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my implementation of the partial trace to use einsum.

```py
def partial_trace(rho, keep, dims, optimize=False):
    """Calculate the partial trace

    ρ_a = Tr_b(ρ)

    Parameters
    ----------
    ρ : 2D array
        Matrix to trace
    keep : array
        An array of indices of the spaces to keep after
        being traced. For instance, if the space is
        A x B x C x D and we want to trace out B and D,
        keep = [0,2]
    dims : array
        An array of the dimensions of each space.
        For instance, if the space is A x B x C x D,
        dims = [dim_A, dim_B, dim_C, dim_D]

    Returns
    -------
    ρ_a : 2D array
        Traced matrix
    """
    keep = np.asarray(keep)
    dims = np.asarray(dims)
    Ndim = dims.size
    Nkeep = np.prod(dims[keep])

    idx1 = [i for i in range(Ndim)]
    idx2 = [Ndim+i if i in keep else i for i in range(Ndim)]
    rho_a = rho.reshape(np.tile(dims,2))
    rho_a = np.einsum(rho_a, idx1+idx2, optimize=optimize)
    return rho_a.reshape(Nkeep, Nkeep)
```

This can be modified to take a vector as input.

```py
def ptrace_outer(u, keep, dims, optimize=False):
    """Calculate the partial trace of an outer product

    ρ_a = Tr_b(|u><u|)

    Parameters
    ----------
    u : array
        Vector to use for outer product
    keep : array
        An array of indices of the spaces to keep after
        being traced. For instance, if the space is
        A x B x C x D and we want to trace out B and D,
        keep = [0,2]
    dims : array
        An array of the dimensions of each space.
        For instance, if the space is A x B x C x D,
        dims = [dim_A, dim_B, dim_C, dim_D]

    Returns
    -------
    ρ_a : 2D array
        Traced matrix
    """
    keep = np.asarray(keep)
    dims = np.asarray(dims)
    Ndim = dims.size
    Nkeep = np.prod(dims[keep])

    idx1 = [i for i in range(Ndim)]
    idx2 = [Ndim+i if i in keep else i for i in range(Ndim)]
    u = u.reshape(dims)
    rho_a = np.einsum(u, idx1, u.conj(), idx2, optimize=optimize)
    return rho_a.reshape(Nkeep, Nkeep)
```

Comment: The above does not seem to work. Consider this toy example using your function `partial_trace()` above.

X = [np.random.randn(3,3), # 0 np.random.randn(4,4), # 1 np.random.randn(2,2), # 2 np.random.randn(3,3), # 3 np.random.randn(7,7), # 4 ] X = [(10*x).round() for x in X] Y = X[0] for k in range(len(X)-1): Y = np.kron(Y, X[k+1]) print(partial_trace(Y, [1], [3,4,2,3,7])) 

The printed function does not return whatever matrix 1 was.

Comment: See the answer below. Unless I missed something your function `partial_trace()` does not compute the partial trace.